# Codebuild was successful, but Jenkins won't stop

Tags: jenkins, amazon-cloudwatch, codebuild

I have a pipeline like this in Jenkins.

I can start Codebuild from Jenkins, but there is a problem with Jenkins not catching Codebuild's exit.

Could you please let me know if you know the cause of this problem?

#### Pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Codebuild start") {
            steps {
                withAWS(region:'ap-northeast-1', credentials:'AWS_CREDENTIAL_KEY')
                {
                    awsCodeBuild(
                        projectName: 'ProjectName',
                        region: 'ap-northeast-1',
                        credentialsType: 'keys',
                        sourceControlType: 'jenkins'
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### IAM

The following IAM roles are granted to users who run Codebuild.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codebuild:StartBuild",
                "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds",
                "codebuild:BatchGetProjects"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow", 
            "Action": [
                "logs:GetLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Environment

- Jenkins is started on AWS EC2 by Docker.
- The security group is also set correctly and you can run jenkins on a GUI basis.
- The AWS Steps plugin and Codebuild plugin are installed in Jenkins.

Thank you.

- Grant logging roles to IAM users.
- Narrow down IAM role's log event resources to specific ones.